# Drools / Guvnor object constructor support

Tags: constructor, dynamic-language-runtime, drools

I am trying to create a new Business Rule Asset via Drools Guvnor 5.1.1.

On the RHS of the rule, I am trying to insert a new fact Java object. This fact Object has a constructor with parameters, with no accessible default constructor (no params). I cant seem to be able to the new fact Object with its parameters. This can be easily done via the DLR, as TestObject o = new TestObject(Obj1).

Is this possible via the Guided rule functionality in Guvnor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do this is to use free form DRL or write a DSL to fit your needs. You can put any java code you want inside the free form DRL textbox.